# Problem deploying hugo's web to git hub pages Error: fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 79431688eb0df78f3b

Tags: git, hugo

I am trying to implement my hugo website in github pages. I am using the "serif-hugo-theme" theme.

It works perfectly for me in local mode but when I do the deployment I get this error.

I have configured the config.toml well with the baseurl of my github repository.

Thanks in advance

Error:

Cloning into '/home/runner/work/la-coladalavanderia/la-coladalavanderia/themes/hugo-serif-theme'...
Error: fatal: remote error: upload-pack: not our ref 79431688eb0df78f3b6d904071895a4d8205ac42
Error: fatal: Fetched in submodule path 'themes/hugo-serif-theme', but it did not contain 79431688eb0df78f3b6d904071895a4d8205ac42. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
Error: The process '/usr/bin/git' **failed with exit code 128**

Comment: You get this kind of error when you've made a superproject commit that says "use commit `79431688eb0df78f3b6d904071895a4d8205ac42` in submodule _____" (fill in the blank), but the `git clone` and `git fetch` that Git runs *in* the submodule doesn't find the specified commit. That usually means someone forgot to `git push` the submodule commit back to GitHub or wherever the submodule repository is stored, but it can also mean that someone put the *wrong hash ID* into the superproject Git repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if I run a git log -1 on the theme path (/themes/hugo-serif theme) it returns: commit 79431688eb0df78f3b6d904071895a4d8205ac42 (HEAD -> master)

But when I try to do the git push I get access denied.

Permission to zerostaticthemes/hugo-serif-theme.git denied to "me".


Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: The push permission-denied error just means that the software managing the repository to which you're sending the new commits (`zerostaticthemes/hugo-serif-theme.git`) has decided that it does not allow you, whoever it thinks you are, to do that. On GitHub that software is their ssh or http server and permissions are controlled by (a) supplying a public key (ssh) or user-name-and-token (https), (b) passing any authentication tests for those, and (c) having permission granted (through their web interface) for the authenticated user.

Comment: If you're using ssh to gain access to github, use `ssh -Tv git@github.com` to see who they think you are. Then that user has whatever permissions. If you're using https, note that the user name *and* the token ("token" is approximately "structured password" here) *combine*, so you'll need a token that has the right permissions. See also GitHub's own help pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a .gitmodules file (which did not exist) with this theme information. _I don't know if it's correct

```
[submodule "themes/hugo-serif-theme"]
path = themes/hugo-serif-theme
url = https://github.com/zerostaticthemes/hugo-serif-theme
```

Comment: Normally you let `git submodule add` create the `.gitmodules` file if you're the person creating the superproject in the first place, and otherwise you use the `.gitmodules` file that whoever created the superproject stored into the superproject. Submodules are tricky to get right. That said, the content here looks OK (though normally the `path` and `url` lines would be indented).